# Tag synonym: [music] -> [audio]

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tag-synonyms

When I was trying to write the tag excerpts for [audio](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio), I realized that I basically had to add a line that states: `questions that do not pertain to music` in the entry since we have both tags.  Then I thought to myself, why should we differentiate between the two?

Audio is a broader term that includes all sound (including [music](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music)).

Answer (score 1):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Both of these tags were removed over the years:

- [music](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) was burned: [The Great Arqade Clean-Up of 2012](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4758/28182)
- [audio](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio) was changed to [audio-hardware](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio-hardware): [Audio tag discussion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5216/28182)