# 'Farming' tag has 2 distinct meanings

Tags: discussion, tags

Just came across the 'farming' tag; which has no summary and two completely different meanings:

- farming for items/loot
- actual agrarian activities

Both are valid classifications, but maybe it would make more sense to either split up into 2 different tags or get rid of both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Destroy it

...and update [the wiki](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4758/the-great-gaming-stack-exchange-clean-up-of-2012) for [The Great Gaming Stack Exchange Clean-Up of 2012](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4758/the-great-gaming-stack-exchange-clean-up-of-2012) once you're done, this is a tag that is already on our burninate list!

### Update

[farming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/farming) is no more. At the expense of the front page, I have removed it from all questions.

Comment: Hooray! (8 more)

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Every tag I burninate, I find two more...

Comment: Burn two tags in the mornin'... Burn two tags at night... Burn two tags before I burn two tags, it makes me feel all right.

Comment: mmm... I wonder if we'll ever get a farming simulator 2011 question some day.

Comment: @yx. I don't think "WTF IS THIS" questions are on topic.

Answer (score 8):

Burninate them both IMO.

There's no particularly strong use case for either of them.

Comment: Agree with this; just dislike keeping it with dual completely-different-and-unneeded meanings