# Can questions be interleaved "newest" and "bumped" in the queue?

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits

Based on my experience from what I am seeing is, when a user that does not have edit permissions edits a post they are placed in a queue. Now if there are no moderators on at the time they sit in the queue and when a user is cleaning up some old posts this quickly stacks up.

The issue is now when a moderator now logs in and approves those edits, one after another. The home page is now filled with old topics and questions that a lot of the time are already answered. Should there be someway to possibly alternative from edited posts and newer questions, or space out the approved edits hitting the front page at once?

**UPDATE**

The issue is apparently being caused by tag edits. Which normally are not a problem but when a mass cleanup is happening, it fills the front page with old unanswered questions.  The possible fix could be to disable tag edits being brought up to the main page. The other option possibly is when editing a tag, give the option to the editor if the post should be brought to the front page?

Listed below is a screenshot showing the issue.

[image]

Comment: The screenshot isn't from edit pileup, actually.  It's a tag cleanup initiative.  See http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4758/the-great-arqade-clean-up-of-2012.

Comment: Perhaps reworded a little I think it is a good suggestion though.  Can questions be interleaved "newest" and "bumped" in the queue.  There is a reluctance to mass edit for this very reason - even when mass edits are warranted.  Creating an automatic interleave would somewhat alleviate that problem.

Comment: In my opinion *tag* edits shouldn't bump a question at all.

Comment: @QAdley No one is blaming you ;D although I do think that the tag edits shouldn't bump a question possibly.

Comment: [Relevant MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/26483/150214).

Comment: Is it just me, or is there absolutely nothing wrong with filling the front page with old *unanswered* questions?  More attention for them.  That said, most of the forntpage spam caused by cleanups isn't unanswered.

Comment: In other words, is it ok if I comment "bump" on a question that I did just a couple of days? I couldn't understand any of this, I still need to improve my english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing is not the result of a backlog in the suggested edits queue, but rather an [ongoing, large scale tag cleanup effort.](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4758/the-great-arqade-clean-up-of-2012)

There's not much we can do to prevent it from taking up a bunch of front page space other than the precautions that are already being taken.

Comment: Those precautions aren't working at all

Comment: @QAdp Oh, you don't have to tell me that. But that doesn't mean there's much we can do about it either. :(

Comment: We cam simply _not_ flood the homepage...

Comment: @QAdp I'm afraid retagging one question per hour or so to avoid flooding is just not feasible.

Comment: *"There's not much we can do to prevent it"* - Ask the developers to not have tag-edits bump a post to the homepage.  I thought you mods had the devs home-phone numbers :) But more seriously, post a `feature-request` on meta.stackoverflow.com (since this is a problem for *all* sites) explaining the problem, then link us back here so we can upvote it.

Comment: @BlueRaja why does everyone seem to think I'm a mod? You aren't the first...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the newest questions page to see the questions in the order they have been asked, rather than in the order they have been edited.  Using both views is (IMO) important for using the site effectively.

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest

Comment: Experienced users know this, but new users coming to our site will see a load of outdated question.

Comment: @QAdley - Hence my post.  To give new users that info.

Comment: Getting new users to read the FAQ is hard enough, expecting them to read meta posts is a bit much :-P

Comment: @QAdley - True, but a new-ish user posted this question and will read this answer.  One down, lots to go.  As an aside, I've never understood why the recent edit view is the default view for everyone.  You don't want new users peer reviewing the edits - that is something the experienced users should be doing, which are the same users that are aware that a tag edit is ongoing.

Answer (score -5):

If the editors are willing to post a **screenshot of the front page before each clean-up** operation in a Meta post, then the rest of us can bump those questions back onto the front page.

The community's here to help!

Comment: Please, no. Frivolous edits with the sole purpose of bumping a post are *highly* frowned upon, for good reason. This is not a solution.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Could you include a link to a discussion or a FAQ on that? Thanks!