# Tag merge request [jungle] -> [league-of-legends]

Tags: discussion, tag-merging

As part of the [Great Arqade Clean-up](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4758/the-great-arqade-clean-up-of-2012) can we get [jungle](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jungle) merged into [league-of-legends](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/league-of-legends) please? All questions against [jungle](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jungle) now only relate to [league-of-legends](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/league-of-legends) at this time.

> If during the process of burning these tags you notice that most of them are all attached to questions about one game (i.e. 10/13 questions tagged with spells is also tagged with skyrim), then just delete the tag from the questions not tagged with that game, and flag one of the remaining ones for moderator attention.

Comment: There are a number of other MOBA type games where you can jungle or at least there is a jungle as a designated "jungler" is less common. It would make more sense IMO to delete the tag than merge it as you cannot really ask a question about jungling without specifying which of the games you mean in. (unless perhaps that question is in what other MOBAS can you jungle etc)

Comment: @Jacxel **READ the reason for the merge** rather than coming up with reasons why they shouldn't be merged that *DO NOT* match the reason for the request. The request to merge Jungle to League of Legends is because Jungle is marked for burning, and every question with Jungle on it ALSO HAS League of Legends on it. Therefore rather than editing posts to remove Jungle and then delete Jungle, simply MERGE Jungle into League of Legends.

Comment: Precisely. Merging is actually a lot less work and will clutter the front page a lot less than a edit-for-removal and delete will, as far as I'm aware. (And all props possible to pixel for doing **so dang many**!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been actioned, meta post was not updated.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, we could introduce something along the lines of [leagueoflegends-jungle]. While this works on SO, I worry that it might be a little too specific for Arqade and will probably just lead to more unneccessary tags...

Comment: Read the original question - and The Great Arqade Clean up thread. This isn't anything to do with the Jungle tag, since it is marked for deletion. This is simply another method of deleting the Jungle tag.