# Merge request [rushing] -> [starcraft-2]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-merging

As part of the Arqade clean up can we get [rushing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rushing) (9 questions, all currently tagged starcraft-2) merged into [starcraft-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2) please?

I know rushing is not a starcraft-2 specific term, however it is currently *only* used on starcraft-2 questions.

Vote to burn please!

**Since people aren't able to read the context of which this is posted** (yes downvoters + Res I mean you). Read this post titled '[The Great Arqade Clean-Up](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4758/the-great-arqade-clean-up-of-2012)', but most specifically THIS PART:

> > We don't want these tags, just burn them. **If during the process of burning these tags you notice that most of them are all attached to questions about one game** (i.e. 10/13 questions tagged with spells is also tagged with skyrim), then just delete the tag from the questions not tagged with that game, and flag one of the remaining ones for moderator attention. The mods will then **merge** the game tag and the tag to be burned, allowing for us to quickly and silently destroy a bunch of tags.

Now since there is no clear definition of flag in this context, and I've already raised [a](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4984/clean-up-world-generation-merge-with-minecraft) [couple](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4976/tag-merge-request-jungle-league-of-legends) of others that went through fine this way *that is why this question exists*.

I am not asking for a merge because the tag is game specific.

I am asking for a merge to **delete** the old tag which is currently **only present on starcraft-2 questions**.

Comment: Lots of negatives with no reasoning why! Suspecting some people aren't aware of the 'merge tags' section on the cleanup thread!

Comment: Merge completed, synonym (obviously) not created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been actioned, meta post was not updated.