# Clean-Up: [framerate] and [performance]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags

I'm not sure if this should be a merge but I think there should be a discussion on it either way. I think having both [framerate](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/framerate) and [performance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) is excessive, and as [performance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) is a more generic term propose a merge/synonym for [framerate](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/framerate) -> [performance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) as [part of the clean up](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4758/the-great-arqade-clean-up-of-2012).

[framerate](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/framerate) has 27 questions, with quite a few of them also having performance tagged
[performance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) has 67 questions.

The solutions I see to this are;

- Dismiss it and keep both
- Review all questions tagged [framerate](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/framerate) and either retag as [performance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) or remove the tag completely, leaving only [name-of-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/name-of-game)
- Merge/Synonym [framerate](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/framerate) to [performance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance)

Comment: I hate both. At minimum `framerate` doesn't seem to provide a usefully distinct categorization from `performance` so a merge is in order.

Comment: I like the framerate tag and performance has been used consistently for non-framerate specific problems. If anything we should see if we could replace performance with more specific tags.

Answer (score 1):

Both tags are still present, so I guess we can consider this as having been status-declined.

I'm tired of community bumps on questions like this, so upvote this answer to get it out of the 'unanswered' queue.

Comment: I've just marked this status-declined which should stop community bumps at least

Comment: @Robotnik It seems that the Community bot, on 2022-07-30, has decided to bump this question despite the [status-declined] tag.

Comment: @galacticninja Hmm, very odd. I thought red tags stopped bumps. Maybe they dont?