# Clean-Up: [graphics-card], [monitor], others -> [hardware]

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a tag [hardware](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware), and then several tags for other components.

Examples:
[monitor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monitor)
[graphics-card](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics-card)
[mouse](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mouse)
[keyboard](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard)
[power-supply](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-supply)
<strike>hard-drive</strike>*

Currently all hardware-related tags to [hardware](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware). Very frequently these tags are used in conjunction with [hardware](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware) anyway, and in the instances that they are they *always* should be anyway, so this is very much a request for discussion in the context of [cleaning up the tags](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4758/the-great-arqade-clean-up-of-2012).

*[hard-drive](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-drive) would not be appropriate to merge due to it's use on consoles.

Would it be possible to do something like a general [input](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/input) and have [keyboard](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard) and [mouse](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mouse) as synonyms, rename [graphics-card](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics-card) to [graphics](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics) and have [monitor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monitor) as a synonym etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I disagree.

I don't like [graphics-card](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics-card), it has a number of issues, but at least it's specific.  [hardware](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware) is simultaneously vague and extremely broad.  As a category I don't think it's useful -- it's 50% of the scope of Super User!<sup>1</sup>  I vote to remove the general tag entirely.

<sub><sup>1</sup>With the other half being software, and yes, I am greatly simplifying their scope.</sub>

Comment: Agreed; `[graphics-card]` *should* be a good tag, as knowledge of various graphics cards is not too uncommon and is fairly orthogonal to other tags (vsync, antialiasing, anisotropic filtering, oh my!).  `[graphics-card]` is a **far** more valid tag imho than others (e.g. `[achievements]`).  The current use may be something of a mess, but that's a separate issue.