# Clean-up: [world-generation] merge with [minecraft]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-merging

Would it be possible to merge [world-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-generation) with [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) as [part of the clean-up](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4758/the-great-arqade-clean-up-of-2012)?

[world-generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-generation) is currently tagged on five questions, all five of which are also tagged with [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request hath been granted.