# Merge request [replays] -> [starcraft-2]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-merging

As part of the [clean up](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4758/the-great-arqade-clean-up-of-2012) can we get [replays](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/replays) merged into [starcraft-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2) please? All of the remaining questions with the tag of [replays](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/replays) all have [starcraft-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2) so this is just a merge request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tag merge completed, synonym not created.