# Player Two Press Burninate? Should we keep the [Multiplayer] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burnination

I'm not convinced that [multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiplayer) is a good or useful tag. It's primary use at the moment is as a meta-tag to allow for filtering of questions concerned specifically with a multiplayer-mode in a game where that differs wildly from the games single player mode, such as the 106 questions currently tagged with both [multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiplayer) and [mass-effect-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect-3). For most similar categories of questions, where there's a large enough number to justify it, we've been moving towards tag suffixes. Thus, I'd propose that [mass-effect-3-multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect-3-multiplayer), which squeezes in just barely beneath the tag limit, be applied to those 106 questions (as well as the, I'm sure, several others that should have it but haven't been double tagged).

As for other possible suffix-tags, We should so probably do this with the [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) overlap as well. I'd argue that if anything, [starcraft-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2) questions should simply be assumed as multiplayer and that we should be more diligent about identifying and properly tagging [starcraft-2-campaign](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2-campaign) questions, if we feel the need to subdivide those at all. The rest of the overlapping tags are sufficiently small in size that I don't see any practical reason to further clutter them with hyphens.

Any objections? If not, I'll add this to the tag cleanup list, and commence burnination, and eventually, request a rename to [mass-effect-3-multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect-3-multiplayer) for the final 106 later this weekend.

Comment: I agree, it will leave some questions in need of new tags creating though (not a problem). I don't think we should have a mass-effect-3-multiplayer though, these are sufficiently stored under just mass-effect-3 imo, there are very few real mechanic changes between single player and multiplayer.

Comment: @pixel I strongly disagree that we don't need a Multiplayer sub tag for ME3, purely on the basis of the sheer number of ME3 questions we have, and the *substantial* differences in gameplay that come from the reduced number of skill points and lack of a controllable squad. It really is a different game.

Comment: Only real difference in multiplayer is a requirement for team-play.  The "substantial" differences you speak of are no different from playing Diablo 3 multiplayer before the hotfixed that removed the additional enemy damage with multiple real players in the party and I don't see a diablo-3-multiplayer tag...

Comment: Oddly enough, Minecraft [already has a namespaced multiplayer tag](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-smp).

Comment: @MarkTrapp why do we do things like this so inconsistently :(

Comment: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/5064/25150 :whisle:

Comment: @pixel ME3 multiplayer has different character classes. The classes that are in common have different skill lists available, and fewer skill points. Some skills and weapons are not available at all. The lack of a squad requires that the player build with different synergies in mind. Some skills, such as the various sniper 'bullet-time' abilities work differently. However, even if *none* of these things were true, the tag could be argued to be helpful simply because most ME3 MP questions deal with classes that *don't exist* in SP, and a new tag acts as a useful filter for searching.

Comment: Minecraft is also going single-player-is-multiplayer soon, which means the distinction will be irrelevant and meaningless.

Comment: @RavenDreamer I don't know if it will ever be permanently meaningless, if only because there's a class of questions (re: those regarding interactions with the multiplayer server), which would benefit from the tag. [tag:minecraft] is big enough to benefit from some subdivision.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Granted. And it's not like Minecraft doesn't have tons of version-specific legacy questions.

Comment: I would keep the [tag:multiplayer] to clarify the difference between single- and multiplayermechanics. Besides that a tag for ME3-MP would confuse user if they need to create an MP-tag for every gamequestion with multiplayerreference or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [COMMENCING BURNINATION.](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4758/the-great-arqade-clean-up-of-2012)

> - [multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiplayer) -  this tag is [scheduled for burnination.](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5114/player-two-press-burninate-should-we-keep-the-multiplayer-tag)
>     **However**, there are a few special caveats:
>
>   1. **DO NOT** remove this tag from any questions which are also tagged as [mass-effect-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect-3). There will be a request to rename
>        [multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiplayer) to [mass-effect-3-multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect-3-multiplayer) at the end of
>        burnination.
>   2. There are a number of other titles where a hyphenated multiplayer tag makes sense. Use your best judgement, and/or follow
>        the example set by other editors to apply these where needed. For
>        example, [ac-revelation-multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ac-revelation-multiplayer) might make sense, though it's
>        borderline. <sup>(CURSE YOU TAG LIMIT!)</sup>

Feedback Request: What should we do with [starcraft-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2). I'm of the opinion that it should *not* have a hyphenate Multiplayer tag, but rather, we should have a [starcraft-2-campaign](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2-campaign) hyphenate tag for Single Player, as it is the smaller subset of the two. Any objections to that?

Comment: +1 I strongly agree with your suggestion on the starcraft-2 tag. The vast majority of starcraft 2 questions are about multiplayer, so it makes more sense to have a campaign tag.

Comment: This is incorrect: *For questions tagged [tag:minecraft], if the question is about running a minecraft server should be tagged [tag:minecraft-server].* We already have a multiplayer tag for [tag:minecraft]: [tag:minecraft-smp].

Comment: Follow-up from chat: if there are questions about Minecraft multiplayer that are about the creative mode (and I'll bet the current market value in trappbucks that if there are, there are only a handful), we should evaluate them to determine if they're really asking about *CMP* or if they're just asking about Creative mode in general. If it's the latter, just use [tag:minecraft]. I don't think we'll have any of the former.

Comment: Follow-up 2 for those playing at home: consensus right now is to wait until at least August 1st when the client/server codebase merge update is released for real and see how it affects Minecraft multiplayer questions before settling on a tag for them.

Comment: Is this happening? Why do I see over 350 questions with [tag:multiplayer]? WHAT'S HAPPENING TO ME?!

Answer (score 0):

To add fuel to the fire,

[civilization-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civilization-5) 402 questions, 242 followers; follower/question = 0.602

[world-of-warcraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-of-warcraft) 372 questions, 255 followers; follower/question = 0.685

[multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiplayer) 387 questions, 21 followers; follower/question = **0.054**

---

Most users appear to agree that the tag isn't useful.