# Let's get rid of [music] once and for all!

Tags: support, tags, deleted-questions

This is the **[only question left](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9409/street-rod-music)**, and it's closed as off-topic. Remove it, and [music](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) will nevermore darken our doorstep!

[Victory is at hand people](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4758/the-great-arqade-clean-up-of-2012)!

Comment: You hate music? BAN!

Comment: @badp - I eat tags like this for breakfast :-P

Comment: @Robotnik I call lies! I see 2 questions with the music tag and this one is still up: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/106566/how-do-you-disable-the-xbox-360-halo-4-edition-startup-sound  :p

Comment: @Lyrion - Damn! That's what I get for leaving my ignored tags on! Removed the music tag from that question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question deleted! Mission accomplished. At least until someone else tags something with [music](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) that is.

Comment: And then we burn it with fire until it goes away again!

Comment: I wonder if there is a game called music to ask questions about just to annoy everyone ;)

Comment: @Lyrion - If and when that day comes, I will delete this question to avoid confusion ;). For now, bask in the glory!