# 404: Reasons for keeping [online] not found

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

So I've recently discovered that we have an [online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online) tag. From a cursory look at the questions in that tag:

- **It's ambiguous** - It's not used for one particular game or service. Not to mention most 'online' services have their own tags. Searching for [[*online*]](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eve-online+or+lord-of-the-rings-online+or+online+or+star-trek-online+or+age-of-empires-online+or+dc-universe-online+or+dungeons-dragons-online+or+wurm-online+or+phantasy-star-online+or+ragnarok-online-2+or+ragnarok-online+or+ultima-online+or+jagged-alliance-online+or+anarchy-online+or+atlantica-online+or+anno-online+or+mu-online+or+mtg-online+or+mechwarrior-online+or+fiesta-online) reveals quite a long list, including but not limited to:

  - [eve-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eve-online)
  - [lord-of-the-rings-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lord-of-the-rings-online)
  - [star-trek-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-online)
  - [age-of-empires-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age-of-empires-online)
  - [dc-universe-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-universe-online)
- **It means different things from game-to-game**. Is it an online service? Is it simply talking about [multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiplayer)? [Is it used almost ironically?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108398/can-starcraft-2-be-played-offline) It's a Type 3 tag, according to the definition on [The Great Arqade Tag Cleanup](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4758/the-great-arqade-clean-up-of-2012)
- **It's not an area of expertise, or a game/platform**. It's not useful as a filter, and it only has 4 followers.

Can the questions stand alone without the online tag? Absolutely. Every question mentions 'online' in the title or body, or is about [an online-only portion of the game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/76624/how-to-use-perks), meaning that the tag isn't even disambiguating the question.

So, as the title states, I can't find any reason for keeping [online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online) around. If there aren't any objections, can we bulk-delete it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't any use of [online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online) that is different than [multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiplayer) *and* that is big enough to justify having its own tag, let alone a tag as broad as "online".

We should synonym it: [online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online) → [multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiplayer).

Alternatively (or as well), we should vigorously edit both out of new questions where the tag is added "just because", rather than categorising the central problem of the question.

Comment: I agree. The only one that kinda doesn't fit the bill is [this one](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1878/what-is-ping-and-why-is-it-important), but it doesn't really need [online] OR [multiplayer], so we could just remove it entirely from that question.