# Audio tag discussion

Tags: discussion, tags

We have [audio](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio), at the moment it's not in a great state and pretty much every question needs retagging. I have posted up [a couple](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5208/tag-sound-system-synonym-request-with-audio) of audio related merge requests for [sound-system](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound-system) and [headset](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/headset) - and [LessPop_MoreFizz has suggested](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5210/tag-headset-synonym-request-with-audio#comment15249_5210) in [one of of them](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5210/tag-headset-synonym-request-with-audio) that we should probably look into retagging the contents of [audio](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio) first.

We have various questions under [audio](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio) that are specifically game related and could just be retagged under [gamename](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gamename) for the specific game it relates to;

- ["Whimsyshire backmasks music"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71596/whimsyshire-backmasks-music) - retag to [diablo-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3)
- ["Half-Life on Steam plays audio from CD while loading"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/62779/half-life-on-steam-plays-audio-from-cd-while-loading) - retag to [half-life](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/half-life)
- ["How can I have different Audio output for Steam Voice chat?"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/57650/how-can-i-have-different-audio-output-for-steam-voice-chat) - retag [steam](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steam)

We also have a variety of platform specific questions under [audio](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio) that specifically relate to a single platform and could be retagged under [platform](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/platform) for the specific game it relates to;

- ["How do I turn off Wii remote sounds?"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35854/how-do-i-turn-off-wii-remote-sounds) - retag to [wii](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wii)
- ["Xbox 360s to tv with HDMI suddenly creating static"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63803/xbox-360s-to-tv-with-hdmi-suddenly-creating-static) - retag to [xbox-360](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-360)

As discussed in [my tag headset meta question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5210/tag-headset-synonym-request-with-audio) we also have questions like these currently under other tags which are audio related but could also be retagged as [platform](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/platform) or [gamename](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gamename);

- ["How can I reset my Xbox 360 wireless headset?"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/61742/how-can-i-reset-my-xbox-360-wireless-headset) - retag as [xbox-360](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-360)
- ["What is the difference between these two official PS3 headsets?"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53415/what-is-the-difference-between-these-two-official-ps3-headsets) - retag as [ps3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ps3)

There are, however, a handful of questions left over that would either be [audio](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio) or another audio related tag, for these I'm in agreement with LessPop_MoreFizz that we should probably have a more specific tag, and simply burn [audio](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio).

The tag suggested for these is [audio-hardware](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio-hardware), and the sort of question I would expect it to contain would be questions like these;

- ["What are the considerations for gaming speakers/headphones?"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20064/what-are-the-considerations-for-gaming-speakers-headphones)
- ["Razer Megalodon problems"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19911/razer-megalodon-problems) - this would also have [technical-issues](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-issues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depreciated [audio](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio) and created [audio-hardware](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio-hardware), retagged all audio questions appropriately as mentioned above.

Comment: semantics quibble here, but I think you may have meant deprecated not depreciated :P